# Cannot access RavenDB Management Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb, ravendb-studio

Try:

1. I created a new project in VS2012
2. I installed via the NuGet package [RavenDB Embedded -Pre](http://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Embedded)
3. I installed [Ninject.MVC3](http://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3)
4. Added a module for ninject RavenDB:

   ```
   Public class RavenDBNinjectModule : NinjectModule
   {
       public override void Load()
       {
       Bind<IDocumentStore>().ToMethod(context =>
       {
           NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
           var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { Url="http://localhost:8080/", DataDirectory="~/App_Data", UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true };
           return documentStore.Initialize();
       }).InSingletonScope();

       Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession()).InRequestScope();
      }
   }
   ```
5. In my class "NinjectWebCommon" ...

   ```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       kernel.Load(new RavenDBNinjectModule());
   }
   ```

When running the application, the following url was generated ("http://localhost:1423")

**Verify that the file "Raven.Studio.xap" was the root of my application**

I tried accessing "http://localhost:8080" but the following screen is displayed: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `documentStore.Initialize` is actually get called?

Comment: If you post code snippets inside a bullet list of items, you need to indent the code by at least 8 spaces (not 4 as usual)

Comment: `documentStore.Initialize` was not running! Thanks, @FitzchakYitzchaki you helped me find the solution.
Write an answer, I'll approve it!

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa could you do an update to how you changed your code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the issue is that `documentStore.Initialize` never get called, because that no one did ask Ninject to resolve `IDocumentStore`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the Url property, which means that you aren't running in embedded mode, but in server mode.
Remove the Url property, and everything will work for you.

Comment: I made the change yet.
`var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { DataDirectory="~/App_Data", UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true };`  
Actually was initially well, but as an attempt to put URL

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

Since he had used `IDocumentSession` in no time, the ninject had not created the instance of `IDocumentStore` and thus not run the `Initialize` method

Comment: So how did you end up solving it? I have the same problem, the first request to my MVC app works and after that the raven studio takes over  the app :)